# Stuck at "if" and it wont continue past it

Tags: python, keyerror

I'm currently stuck at line 22, if I input 15 km instead of 15 miles it won't continue towards the `elif` statement which is ment to convert 15 km into miles.

I have tried switching key & values, and been trying to figure out how the code works logically.

```
distance = {}
km_miles = input("Type distasnce and unit (miles or km)\n>>>")
value, key = km_miles.split(" ")
distance[key] = float(value)

if distance[key] == distance['miles']:
    print("Printing from miles to kilometers")
    print(miles_to_km(distance[key]))

elif distance[key] == distance['km']:
    print("Printing from kilometers to miles")
    print(km_to_miles(distance[key]))

else:
print("try again")
```

What I'm expecting it to do is that if I type 15 km, its meant to enter the `elif distance[key] == distance['km']` and not just fail at line 22.

if I didn't type either miles or km. Then I would expect it to print out "try again".

Comment: Where is your `miles_to_km` method defined?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What does `distances['miles']` contain? Are you sure you don't want to run your check to simply compare `key` to `miles` or `km`?

Comment: There aren't even 22 lines in the code you show. Please create a [mcve] to show us, and if you get some error then please copy-paste it in full and complete into your question. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `distance` is an empty dictionary. What do you expect from doing `distance['miles']`?

Comment: `KeyError` means that your dictionary lacks key you have asked for. When user input is 15 km then you add pair `km,15` to your dictionary, but in `if` statement you compare it to *value for key 'miles'* as there is no such entry it causes error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely lost with logic flow here. To debug your issue, try printing `distance` variable before `if/else` statement, you'll see what's wrong with it.

If you need to check the units, just do

```
value, unit = km_miles.split(" ")
if unit == 'miles':
    ...
elif unit == 'km':
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to complicate things, just `split()` by spaces, get the value and they key i.e. unit (km or miles):

```
def km_to_miles(x):
    print("{} km to miles method".format(x))

def miles_to_km(x):
    print("{} miles to km method".format(x))

distance = {}
km_miles = input("Type distasnce and unit (miles or km)\n>>>")
value, key = km_miles.split(" ")

if key == 'km' or key == 'miles':    
    if key == 'miles':
        print("Printing from miles to kilometers")
        print(miles_to_km(value))

    elif key == 'km':
        print("Printing from kilometers to miles")
        print(km_to_miles(value))

    else:
        print("try again")
else:
    print("Error: Invalid unit, Please try again")
```

> Note: I also added a check to make sure the units are either in `km`
>   or `miles`

OUTPUT:

```
Type distasnce and unit (miles or km)
>>>15 km
Printing from kilometers to miles
15 km to miles method
None
```